# How Would I Go About Aggregating Text Results Into A Singular Temporary Column?

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb

I have a database. From this database, I have queried and received the results:

```
Breed   |   Name
Mastiff |   John
Golden  |   Jojo
Shih Tzu|   Mimi
Poodle  |   John
Labrador|   Jojo
Mastiff |   Jojo
```

And I was hoping to learn how I would be able to manipulate the data so that the results would look something like this - or (however the SQL operating procedure is)

```
Breed   | Names
Mastiff | John, Jojo
Labrador| Jojo
Golden  | Jojo
Shih Tzu| Mimi
Poodle  | Jojo
```

Where basically the Breeds' have had all the names pointing to them aggregated to them.
Like COUNT() but for Strings

Comment: which rdbms are you using? (mysql, oracle, sql server, etc)

Comment: I am using MariaDB

Comment: why `Shih Tzu` and `Poodle` is not available? is it intentional?

Comment: Sorry, they are available. I'll edit it in a second. But I didn't include them to emphasize the difference in how I wanted the second column to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with [GROUP_CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/)

```
SELECT 
  Breed, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Name SEPARATOR ', ') Names
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY Breed 
ORDER BY Breed;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can use [string aggregation function `group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select breed, group_concat(name) names
from mytable
group by breed
```